# Structure of dihydrogen peroxy-phosphate ion

Tags: molecular-structure, resonance, pnictogen

In structure of Dihydrogen peroxy-phosphate ion $\ce{H2PO5-}$, shouldn't negative charge be on oxygen linked directly to phosphorus, rather than on oxygen linked through peroxy linkage with another oxygen? Since in former it will be in resonance with $\mathrm{p}\pi-\mathrm{d}\pi$ multiple bond between phosphorus and oxygen, while in latter these is no resonance. But my friend argues with me that it should be on latter, since there will be much higher stabilisation by inductive effect and there are only two canonical structures of $\ce{H2PO5-}$.